# GCM Push notification not received on single device android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

GCM Push notification is not received to one device alone. It is working fine with other mobile devices. GCM token is registered and it is active. But the notification is pushed but not received. The device model which is not receiving is Moto G4. To other users who uses this device model are receiving the notification. Please help in finding the issue. I tried re-installing the application and also cleared the cache. But no solution found.

Comment: do you having issue only on moto g 4 devices ?  and why not use FCM instead?

Comment: reset your device and install that app and test......

Comment: Do you have a Google account on that device and updated Google Play Services package?

Comment: @akshay_shahane : Not on all moto g4 devices. Only on this single device.

Comment: @PCGALIANDROID : I tried re-installing the app. But its not working!

Comment: reset your device and then try...

Comment: @EugenPechanec: But the google play services is updated only. It is not showing any software update.

Comment: @AmalaAdithyha I have posted an answer. Please check and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. First confirm once if there is no error message returned from GCM server. Check if the notification priority is 'high' in gcm/fcm send api
2. Try the code *#*#426#*#* to check the hear beat status of your google play services.
3. Check if there are any device specific settings like 'Disabling autostart option'[in MIUI devices], 'no notification in locked state'[in oppo devices] or any security apps the kills your app if the app is in background.

Comment: FYI The correct code to open the Google Play Services debug app seems to be `*#*#426#*#*`